# Understanding fibonacci ratio in plants

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Recently, a 13year old kid has re-dicovered that there is a magic ratio for branching in plants. Following article describes his work in his own words.

http://www.amnh.org/nationalcenter/youngnaturalistawards/2011/aidan.html

> In 1754, a naturalist named Charles Bonnet observed that plants sprout
>   branches and leaves in a pattern, called phyllotaxis. Bonnet saw that
>   tree branches and leaves had a mathematical spiral pattern that could
>   be shown as a fraction. The amazing thing is that the mathematical
>   fractions were the same numbers as the Fibonacci sequence! **On the oak
>   tree, the Fibonacci fraction is 2/5, which means that the spiral takes
>   five branches to spiral two times around the trunk to complete one
>   pattern.** Other trees with the Fibonacci leaf arrangement are the elm
>   tree (1/2); the beech (1/3); the willow (3/8) and the almond tree
>   (5/13) (Livio, Adler).

I'm facing difficulty in understanding highlighted statement. He says fibonacci fraction for 2/5 means that spiral takes five branches to siral two times around the trunk.

Implies, Angle between each branch is 720/5 = 144 degrees.

But the kid says,

> The pattern was about 137 degrees and the Fibonacci sequence was 2/5.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article implies that, *asymptotically*, the spiral takes $F_n$ (the $n$-th [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)) branches to go $F_{n+2}$ times around the trunk of the tree. The fraction $2/5$ is only a first approximation to this phenomenon (the other cited approximations being $1/2,1/3,3/8,5/13$). The limiting ratio is $1/\phi^2$, where $\phi$ is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$. Hence the rotation angle between branches should be approximately $360^\circ / \phi^2\approx137.507764^\circ$.

---

To see why the ratio is what it is, first let's define the ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers, in the limit, to be $$\phi = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}.$$

(We'll leave aside the question of why this limit exists, i.e. why the Fibonacci numbers exhibit exponential growth.) Then, by the recurrence definition of Fibonacci numbers, we have

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n}=1+\left(\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}\right)^{-1}\to1+\phi^{-1}.$$

Hence $\phi$ solves the equation $x=1+1/x$. This can be multiplied through for the quadratic equation $$x^2-x-1=0.$$

The golden ratio $\phi$ must be the positive solution, $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$. Now note that $$\frac{F_n}{F_{n+2}}=\left(\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\right)^{-1}\to\phi^{-1}\cdot\phi^{-1}=1/\phi^2.$$